# what is the performance of if-else statement in python

Tags: performance, python-2.7

I am using if else in my python code. I am wondering how many if else i can add without impacting perfomance of my script.

after what number of if else statements, performance of my script goes down??

Comment: If you notice your script is slow, then ask the question. As for now, the only answer is that in general it is unlikely to be a performance issue. However, it might be a bad design choice. I have a feeling you might want to use dictionary... But it is impossible to say anything more useful without knowing more details.

Comment: I haven't a clue.  Why don't you do some experiments and tell us -- how many if statements can you add to your script before performance goes down ?

Comment: As a general rule, if `elif` statements are affecting your performance, then your application isn't performance sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

the number of them doesn't really matter. It's what's inside them that will decide on performance. The time it takes to evaluate an if else statement is really really tiny. Plus there are tricks the compiler uses to make it even faster, so you really shouldn't worry about it.